# How to use java dependencies to xamarin android project?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.ekodevelops:eko-gateway-android-sdk:1.2.0'
}
```

Want to create a *.aar file and use it my Xamarin android project 
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

We could use the following steps to create a Bindings Library from the .AAR file:

1. Create a new Java Bindings Library project.
2. Add a single .AAR file to the project. A binding project may only
   contain a single .AAR.
3. Set the appropriate build action for the .AAR file.
4. Choose a target framework that the .AAR supports.
5. Build the Bindings Library.

then we could add a reference to the Bindings Library in your Xamarin.android project.

for details, please refer to [Binding an .AAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar)

Comment: I followed this process,but I can access the java class methods.But I am not able to use the payment gateway SDK.